# What does gcc -rpath combined with -W1 mean?

Tags: gcc, user-defined-functions, gcc-warning

I can see from [`man gcc`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc) that `-W` has something to do with warnings, but I cannot work out exactly what `-W1` would be doing. I am building using the following my Makefile.am:

```
lib_mysqludf_ssdeep_la_LDFLAGS = -module -avoid-version -no-undefined -rpath @MYSQL_PLUGINDIR@ @SSDEEP_LIBDIR@ @SSDEEP_LIBS@
```

Just fine on Ubuntu, but RedHat (RHEL) is throwing a 'paths must be absolute error` so after finding [a post to the gtk mailing list](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-list/2002-July/msg00042.html) I tried:

```
lib_mysqludf_ssdeep_la_LDFLAGS = -module -avoid-version -no-undefined -W1,--rpath -W1,@MYSQL_PLUGINDIR@ @SSDEEP_LIBDIR@ @SSDEEP_LIBS@
```

Which works, but I cannot see why and I would like to find out before relying upon it as a fix for my Redhat build issue.

*Update* It looks like redhat is not supplying a path to @MYSQL_PLUGINDIR@ and therefore -rpath is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that is W1 - not Wl (i.e. the letter el ) ?

Look at the Linker options section of gcc's man page

Comment: After copying and pasting into my editor I believe you are correct and it should be `-Wl` and not `-W1`. But that now breaks the build! :)

Comment: It looks like redhat is not supplying a path to @MYSQL_PLUGINDIR@ and therefore -rpath is failing.